# MelonJS prerendering on mobile

Tags: javascript, game-engine, melonjs

I´m working on a game using [MelonJS](http://www.melonjs.org/). To increase performance on mobile devices, i tried to use prerendering.
But on all mobile Apple devices (iPod, iPhone, iPad) all tile-layer won´t be shown!
It seems like MelonJS cannot draw in or read out of the background-prerender-canvas.

Does anyone have this problem too? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There have been a couple of fixes for the "preRender" feature in melonJS 0.9.7 (currently in beta). If you can build it from source, give it a try! It's definitely working for me on iPhone 4S/iOS 6.1